# python find differing elements in list

Tags: python, list, function

I want to compare lists of this kind:

```
A = [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
B = [0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
```

and find out what elements differ. In this case it should return index 5 of A and index 7 of B. All the other elements are the same. Is there a function for this?

best, US

Comment: Why not index 5 of B or index 7 of A? Are you assuming any pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> [index for (_, index) in set(zip(A, xrange(len(A)))) - set(zip(B, xrange(len(B))))]
[5, 7]
```

What on earth is this doing?

1. Zip the list with incrementing numbers. So, produce a list of tuples where the first value is the element in the list, and the second is its index.
2. Create sets of out each, so they can be compared with set functions. Tuples are immutable, therefore hashable, therefore can be stored in a set
3. Take the set difference between the two
4. Pick out the index of the different items

**EDIT**

Thanks to Roman's comment, this is simpler, but does the same thing.

```
>>> [index for (index, _) in set(enumerate(A)) - set(enumerate(B))]
[5, 7]
```

Note that while `zip` produces a list, `enumerate` produces an enumerable, which is immediately enumerated to build the list. Also it produces tupes of type `(index, value)` rather than `(value, index)` as in the above answer.

Comment: `zip(A, xrange(len(A)))` is `enumerate(A)`

Comment: Ok but I miss xrange function. Which module is it in?

Comment: xrange is in the standard lib

Comment: Thanks! That's almost correct. It's the same as `zip(xrange(len(A), A))` and produces an enumerable rather than a list. I've incorporated it into my answer.

Comment: @VascoP in Python 2.x, not in Python 3.

Comment: Shortened: zip(*set(enumerate(A)) - set(enumerate(B)))[0]

Answer (score 1):

Do you necessarily want a one-liner? Because otherwise there's more simple code:

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    if A[i]!=B[i]:
        print i
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should do the trick (untested):

```
[i for i, v in enumerate(zip(A, B)) if sum(v) == 1]
```

This will return list of numbers of elements that have different values in each list.

If your data set is different than in the question, then you could use this:

```
[i for i, v in enumerate(zip(A, B)) if v[0] != v[1]]
```

Comment: As long as it is only 1s and 0s!

Comment: @jamylak: This means "_exactly as in the question!_" :)

Comment: unless someone tries to find differing items in two different types of lists, nevermind hahaha

Comment: @jamylak: "_two different types of lists_"? In Python `list` is one type, there are no "two types of lists", unless you had tuple in mind, but it would behave the same way here, dict or set, but they are definitely not lists (see some Python tutorial for details), or just a _sequence_,but this would be a major misunderstanding to call it a list.

Comment: No i meant different as in not 1s and 0s eg.
[2,0,2]
[0,0,2]
which would no sum to 1... argh dont worry it was all a big misunderstanding...

Answer (score 1):

Another (perhaps more readable?) one-liner:

```
>>> [index for (index,(a,b)) in enumerate(zip(A,B)) if a!=b]
[5, 7]
```

This first zips the lists together:

```
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0), 
(1, 1), (0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 0)]
```

And then attaches an index to the items with the `enumerate()` function:

```
[(0, (0, 0)), (1, (1, 1)), (2, (0, 0)), (3, (1, 1)), (4, (0, 0)), (5, (1, 0)), 
(6, (0, 0)), (7, (0, 1)), (8, (0, 0)), (9, (1, 1)), (10, (0, 0)), (11, (1, 1)), 
(12, (0, 0)), (13, (1, 1)), (14, (0, 0))]
```

It then uses a fairly standard [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to compare the items an builds a list of indices where the items do not match.

Comment: Your answer is very similar to mine. Do you agree?

Comment: I do agree. Yours was posted while I was writing mine... would you like me to delete my answer?

Comment: Then you were writing your answer for 20 minutes until you posted it ;) No, if you would like it to stay, then do not delete it. But please add some value so it is not treated by others as "copy & paste" answer.

Comment: It was posted as untested, because I was writing it on my phone. I took the time to write it on a small keyboard. But anyway thanks for testing my answer, I will update it with statement that it has been tested ;)

Comment: Cool, no problem @Tadeck. All I can say is, you must have a very fancy phone, and a keen desire to answer on SO... I salute you!

Comment: Touch-enabled smartfone. Plus I believe such answers can be given without the need to fully test them. At some point, with some knowledge, such solutions just come up without keyboard and interpreter at your disposal. Some day you will not need them to solve such questions :)